# How to Cut Datetime Data Type in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a Datetime data type `12/30/2015 11:30:00 AM` so, while on the SQL server, it will be `fromDate.ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd HH: mm tt")` results it is `2016-01-01 12: 30: 00,000` and I want to cut the string data portion only days and hours and minutes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change your

```
.ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd HH: mm tt") 
//showing: year (yyyy), month (MM), day of month (dd), hour (HH), minute (mm), and "The AM/PM designator" (tt)
```

to

```
.ToString ("dd HH:mm")
//showing: day of month (dd), hour (HH), and minute (mm) only
```

[More](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) about `DateTime` format which you might find very useful. The explanations are given with handy samples and are quite complete.

Edit:

To interpret such text data from `SQL`, use `.Substring(int index, int length)`

```
string text = sqltext.Substring(("2016-01-").Length, 9); //the 9 must be from your days to your minutes. If the text string is shorter/longer, change this value
```

Here is the explanation of the two `Substring` arguments:

1. `index` argument starts from `0` offset of the text.

   Suppose your text is `2016-01-01 12: 30: 00,000` then `index = 0` will point to the first `2`, `index = 1` to the first `0` and so on. To grab the day part's first digit `0`, you need to have index of `7` according to your input. But easier way to determine the `index` is by taking **all** the `string` **before** your wanted position and grab its `Length` (which is what I show: `"2016-01-").Length`.
2. `length` argument gives the number of characters you want to take from `index` point onward.

   Since you want to take `01 12: 30` consisting total of `9` characters (note your `white spaces`) you should put `9`. Or you can be more generic by putting `("01 12: 30").Length` too:

   ```
   string text = sqltext.Substring(("2016-01-").Length, ("01 12: 30").Length);
   ```

Additional note by [Mr. James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622140/james) (see comment): "Please note that the "days" given for this answer is the [day of the month](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), which can in no case be more than 31... If you want the number of days from some baseline date, you'd have to do `DateTime` subtraction and use a `TimeSpan.ToString`."

Comment: I retrieve data from SQL server in the data retrieved so. and when I get the data up I just wanted to take the day and hour and minute

Comment: Please note that the "days" given for this answer is the day of the month, which can in no case be more than 31.  The question is not clear on whether or not that makes a difference.  If you want the number of days from some baseline date, you'd have to do DateTime subtraction and use a TimeSpan.ToString.

Comment: @James thanks for pointing it out, I edited my answer and make reference to your comment and MSDN source.